# Read .txt field data from /storage/emulated/ path in android 11

Tags: android, file, android-11, android-external-storage

I want to read data from `.txt` file from /storage/emulated application-specific path. I have written data successfully in same file but not able to read it.

Code to write data in txt file.

```
val writer: FileOutputStream = openFileOutput(file.absolutePath, MODE_PRIVATE)
writer.write(str1.toByteArray())
writer.flush()
writer.close()
```

Trying to read data from same file.

```
val text = StringBuilder()
val br = BufferedReader(FileReader(file))
var line: String?
while (br.readLine().also { line = it } != null) {
 text.append(line)
 text.append('\n')
 }
 br.close()
```

line returning null value.

Comment: Getting `null` from `readLine()` means the end of the stream has been reached.

Comment: Okay but the file length is 0 while trying to read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write to the location `/storage/emulated` directory. You avhave used `openFileOutput()` . It points to where `getFilesDir()` on Context returns. You can tell this because the documentation says:

> Returns the absolute path to the directory on the filesystem where files created with openFileOutput(String, int) are stored.

To read from your location, use `openFileInput()`, the corresponding method on Context with the same filename that you had passsed to the `openFileOutput()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try adding android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" to your manifest.
```

Or change it to comply to Android 11's new scoped storage system.
See https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage

Comment: I have already added these.

Comment: Please your manifeast  

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

And your  file path  read from external storage -> 

Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + filename

Answer (score 0):

> I want to read data from .txt file from /storage/emulated application-specific path. I have written data successfully in same file but not able to read it.

You did not write to a location in a `/storage/emulated` directory. You used `openFileOutput()`. That writes to a different location. To read from that location, use `openFileInput()`, the corresponding method on `Context`. Be sure to use the same filename that you passed to `openFileOutput()`.